# server side include not working with Google drive web hosting

Tags: include, server-side, google-drive-api, ssi

I recently started using Google Drive to host my little website ([www.warriner.info](http://www.warriner.info))

Up until now I have been using javascript and document.write() to generate html that is repeated on many pages (ie: the navigation menu bar). I'm trying to switch to using Server Side Includes, but it seems that it's not supported by Google Drive.

What I mean by not supported is that I put the #include lines in my html code, but they just appear as comments and don't actually include anything.

If you go the URL above and look at the source of my main page, you'll see what I mean.

Does anyone else have any experience using SSI with Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

SSI's are an feature of Apache -webservers [mod_include module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html).